# How do I punctuate coordinated phrases containing ellipted PPs?

Tags: punctuation, commas, coordination

Consider the following examples:

> You need to have a clear idea of, and strategy for, X

> They all agreed with, and contributed to, X

> We hope the company will benefit from, and make use of, X

Is punctuation correct in these examples, or should I lose the commas? I realise that in most cases it's possible to rephrase, but I need to know how to treat this exact construction.

Comment: Today I learned the word **ellipted**, which I had never heard before.  (I knew *ellipsis*, but not that there was a verb form.)

Comment: @stangdon  Now I'm dead proud :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the punctuation is correct. The commas are needed to demarcate the second phrase, making it clear that it's a second concept also relating to 'X'.